# JavaFX FliteredList not following the change of underlying list

Tags: javafx, observablelist

I have an ArrayList of Integers (aList), and then made an ObservableList (oList) from aList.  Add 0 to 10 to aList, then made a FilteredList (fList) out the oList.  Finally, I added 10 to aList and 11 to oList. I expected to see both 10 and 11 in fList, but surprisingly, 10 is NOT in fList.  Is it an expected behavior or a bug?

```
    List<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<>();
    ObservableList<Integer> oList = FXCollections.observableList(aList);
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        aList.add(i);
    FilteredList<Integer> fList = new FilteredList<Integer>(oList, i -> { return i > 5; });
    aList.add(10);
    oList.add(11);
    System.out.print("O: ");
    for (Integer i : oList)
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.print("F: ");
    for (Integer i : fList)
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
    System.out.println("");
```

Here is the output, 10 is not in fList:

```
    O: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
    F: 6, 7, 8, 9, 11,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected (or at least, explainable) behavior. The [documentation for `FXCollections.observableList(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList-java.util.List-) says:

> Note that mutation operations made directly to the underlying list are not reported to observers of any ObservableList that wraps it.

The `FilteredList` works by observing its source list (`oList`) and updating its content when the content of `oList` changes. Since no notification is fired that `oList` added the value `10`, the filtered list never adds it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.